# How to iterate through a pandas dataframe, column by column returning items one at a time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe called rollStocks:

```
         roll_418_oe_2015-03-13, roll_419_oe_2015-03-20, roll_420_oe_2015-03-27
0,       BBG.XWBO.VIG.S,         BBG.XWBO.VIG.S,         BBG.XPAR.ACA.S,   
1,       BBG.XPAR.ACA.S,         BBG.XPAR.ACA.S,         BBG.XSTO.LUPE.S,   
2,       BBG.XSWX.ALPH.S,        BBG.XSWX.ALPH.S,        BBG.XSWX.ALPH.S,   
3,       BBG.XCSE.MAERSKB.S,     BBG.XCSE.MAERSKB.S,     BBG.XCSE.MAERSKB.S,   
4,       BBG.XBRU.GBLB.S,        BBG.XBRU.GBLB.S,        BBG.XSWX.SPSN.S,   
5,       BBG.XPAR.IPN.S,         BBG.XLIS.EDPR.S,        BBG.XBRU.GBLB.S,   
6,       BBG.XLON.BNZL.S,        BBG.XPAR.GFC.S,         BBG.XLON.BNZL.S,
```

I need to iterate though each column (one column at a time) taking each entry in the column and retrieving time-series data from files with the same names as the entries and entering this data into a another dataframe which I will then use in a process.  Once the first column has finished I will go onto the next column in the rollStocks dataframe and do the same until I reach the end of the rollStocks dataframe.

Could someone let me know how I loop through each column in the rollStocks dataframe to obtain each individual item in the column allowing me to obtain the timeseries for each item in the column and process that data before moving onto the next rollStocks column please?

I have tried

```
for colEntry in rollStocks.columns:
            colStock = rollStocks.loc[:,colEntry]
```

but this just iterated through all of the columns in the entire dataframe without allowing me to process the data one column at a time.

Comment: Sorry it's unclear to me what you're asking here, each entry in each column is the filename or is it an entry in another df you're trying to filter? All your code is doing is just retrieving each column you can simplify it to just `for col in rollStocks: colStock = rollStocks[col]` but what are you going to do with `colStock`?

Comment: "taking each entry in the column and retrieving time-series data from files with the same names as the entries" This sounds like you want to do a "join" operation. In pandas this is done with the `merge` function.

Comment: Hi EdChum,  each entry in each column is a file name.  I would like to go though each column one at a time picking up the entries and opening the corresponding files.  The colStock was suppose to be the individual entry in a column

Comment: Then I think something like `for col in rollStocks: for row in rollStocks[col]: colSock = pd.read_csv(row)` should work

Comment: Thanks EdChum, Works a treat x

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process every element in your df to read a csv then the following should work:

```
for col in rollStocks: 
    for row in rollStocks[col]: 
        colSock = pd.read_csv(row)
```

Alternatively you could call [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap):

```
rollStocks.applymap(pd.read_csv)
```

The above assumes that the default params and your paths are acceptable